# Magento-Some of the products giving 404 error

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

This is really strange. Some of the products from the catalog gives 404 error, even if targeted directly.

The product can be seen in admin and is enabled with stock set. I checked the URL rewrite section but couldn't find anything. Also, tried reindexing everything, but couldn't resolve the issue. Even flushed the cache still nothing.

After searching the issue, I found a solution saying running an SQL command. I did that but it said the entry already exists.

Even when I search the product in catalog, nothing returns. The item is there but its just redundant and not showing.

Comment: Are you sure it marked as `in stock`, is `enabled`, visible for `catalog and search`, has positive stock qty, assigned to appropriate website?

Comment: ya..these all are checked and correct.

Comment: try to re-save product. if it will not help then take a look if its rewrite rule is inside of `Catalog\Manage Rewrite Rules`.

Comment: url rewrite is happening. everything seems correct. I tried creating a duplicate, it didnt worked either.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that the product is...

1. **Assigned to a website**
2. Inventory level is above 0 and status is in stock
3. Enabled
4. Visible in catalog/search

I have highlighted point 1 as it does tend to catch people out in a multi store environment.

Also, you may need to reindex/clear cache etc.

Finally, double check you are using the correct suffix if relevant i.e. you may have to add .html to the url.

Comment: To add to Drews answer check the store scope. Check each store view as the urls/settings might be different to default.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your product's **status** is **'Enabled'**.

Answer (score 0):

Re-indexing may help you to resolved the issue.

Go to admin panel System > Index Management. Here select all and do re-indexing. After doing re-indexing try to clear your magento cache and check.